# calamp Event Report Table

Tags: java, tracking

Please does anyone know how to obtain the *Event Report Table* for **calamp lmu** messaging units.

ex: code event = 50, ,11. ???

thanks.

Comment: I mean the mapping between event codes and what they mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calamp has a documentation for their product ,just you should have an account https://puls.calamp.com/wiki

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your response .

Answer (score 1):

I contacted CalAmp. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to share any of their documentation.